# The result does not match when using Float32Array in chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm learning the way to use Float32Array, but while define a new data I found it was not match the uint32 answer.
I enter the data in console and find the wrong answer.

```
> const test = new Float32Array(1)
< undefined
> test[0] = 0x0a0b0c0d
< 168496141
> test[0]
< 168496144
```

And then I define a 28-bit data, it works well

```
> test[0] = 0x0a0b0cd
< 10531021
> test[0]
< 10531021
```

So how could I use 32 bit to define a data?

Comment: floats never have 100% accuracy

Comment: Float32Array, as the name implies, holds 32 bit floats. Per [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values): `Integers between 0 and 16,777,216 can be exactly represented (also applies for negative integers between −16,777,216 and 0). Integers between 2^24=16,777,216 and 2^25=33,554,432 round to a multiple of 2 (even number). Integers between 2^25 and 2^26 round to a multiple of 4.` Since `168,496,141` lies between `2^27` and `2^28`, using a 32 bit float will round to multiple of 16